# Installed PDFInfo with Homebrew Cask but no command associated with "pdfinfo"

Tags: shell, osx, homebrew

I installed `pdfinfo` with Homebrew Cask:

```
brew cask install pdfinfo
```

It's successfully installed. But it's **not activated as a command** in the shell:

```
> pdfinfo
-bash: pdfinfo: command not found
```

What I don't understand is that I did the exact same procedure with `pdftotext` (installed with Homebrew Cask), and it works fine:

```
> brew cask install pdftotext
(...)
> pdftotext
pdftotext version 3.03
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pdfinfo command line tool is part of the xpdf package:

```
brew install xpdf
```

This package installs many things, including pdfinfo.